# Pygments error: no lexer for alias - Underscores in code block

Tags: jekyll, github-pages, pygments, github-flavored-markdown, redcarpet

I'm working on a github-pages project with all the usual suspects.  I'm trying to switch my markdown from kramdown to redcarpet to better support GFM for local development.  I have an existing project that has just one troublesome section of markdown.  It's a single-line code block with a variable name containing underscores.

````
```function_field_name```
````

_config.yml

```
markdown: redcarpet

redcarpet:
  extensions: ["tables", "autolink", "strikethrough", "space_after_headers", "with_toc_data",  "no_intra_emphasis", "fenced_code_blocks"]

highlighter: pygments
safe: true
```

I get the following error:

> Conversion error: There was an error converting 'queries.md'. jekyll
>   2.2.0 | Error:  Traceback (most recent call last):   File "/Users/shawnjohnson/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/pygments.rb-0.6.0/lib/pygments/mentos.py",
>   line 303, in start
>       res = self.get_data(method, lexer, args, kwargs, text)   File "/Users/shawnjohnson/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/pygments.rb-0.6.0/lib/pygments/mentos.py",
>   line 171, in get_data
>       res = self.highlight_text(text, lexer, formatter_name, args, _convert_keys(opts))   File "/Users/shawnjohnson/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/pygments.rb-0.6.0/lib/pygments/mentos.py",
>   line 122, in highlight_text
>       lexer = self.return_lexer(lexer, args, kwargs, code)   File "/Users/shawnjohnson/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/pygments.rb-0.6.0/lib/pygments/mentos.py",
>   line 79, in return_lexer
>       return lexers.get_lexer_by_name(lexer, **inputs)   File "/Users/shawnjohnson/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/pygments.rb-0.6.0/vendor/pygments-main/pygments/lexers/**init**.py",
>   line 98, in get_lexer_by_name
>       raise ClassNotFound('no lexer for alias %r found' % _alias) ClassNotFound: no lexer for alias 'function_field_name```' found

Answer (score 1):

Your backticks must be positionned like this :

````
``` javascript
function_field_name
```
````

But with backtics you will have no highlighting. Prefer highlight tag

```
{% highlight javascript %}
function_field_name
{% endhighlight %}
```

Plus : if you want kramdown to be GFM complient just add this to _config.yml

```
markdown: kramdown

kramdown:
  # use Github Flavored Markdown
  input: GFM
  # do not replace newlines by <br>s
  hard_wrap: false
```

Comment: I didn't test everything, but I was looking for strike through support, and the kramdown+GFM wasn't doing the trick.  Based on [this article](http://ajoz.github.io/2014/06/29/i-want-my-github-flavored-markdown/) I went w/ redcarpet.  Also, when I used the multiline backtics the formatting came out a bit different.  Good tip on using the highlight tag, I'll give that a try.

Answer (score 0):

I found what was going wrong, it is rather a stupid question (:

You see the log : ```` ClassNotFound: no lexer for alias 'function_field_name```' found ````, where ```` function_field_name``` ```` is actually what you putted inside the highlighter syntax. You should put your desired language like `javascript` or others, instead of ```` function_field_name``` ````.

Pygments gave you the error message because there is no programming language called '```` function_field_name``` ```` . I am sure you just started with the pygments and you just copied the source code from somewhere else.

To make it even clear, you should use

```
{% highlight javascript %}
function_field_name
{% endhighlight %}
```

Not:

````
{% highlight function_field_name```  %}
function_field_name
{% function_field_name```  %}
````